# Cookies in python

Tags: python, cookies

I am trying to write a script in python which uses the Cookie library to set cookies. I have written the following method:

```
import uuid
import Cookie
import sys
import os

def send_cookie(key, value, max_age):
    cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    cookie[key]=value
    cookie[key]['max-age']=max_age
    print cookie.output()
```

The problem is when I call this method multiple times for example, send_cookie('foo',123,1000), send_cookie('foo2',12345,1000).
I would 'assume' that these cookies are stored onto my computer. When I print the os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE'], I dont't see any of the cookies I set in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `Cookie` module only helps you model the abstract concept of a cookie, and perhaps generate `Set-Cookie` headers. An additional module [`cookielib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html) can handle collections of cookies, but neither will set a `HTTP_COOKIE` environment header.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html) is quite clear on this:

> The `Cookie` module defines classes for abstracting the concept of cookies, an HTTP state management mechanism. It supports both simple string-only cookies, and provides an abstraction for having any serializable data-type as cookie value.

The `HTTP_COOKIE` environment variable is something a *CGI server* would set based on an incoming HTTP request. You certainly could generate such an environment variable from the `Cookie` object, but the act of creating such an object does not affect the environment on its own.

If you are actually using this function in a CGI script, then the `cookie.output()` should be part of the HTTP headers; make sure you haven't already sent the double line separator signalling to the CGI server that your headers are done.

Comment: But when I print the cookie.output(), wouldn't my browser store that cookie.

Comment: And the next time I open the script, my browser should pass that stored cookie into os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']?

Comment: @user136638: Not unless you send that output to your browser as a HTTP response.

Comment: @user136638: if a browser has received a valid cookie, then the browser will follow the normal cookie rules and send it back to the origin server, yes.

Comment: @user136638: but your question doesn't have any context to show that you are actually interacting with a browser through a CGI script.

Comment: Oh, I am actually trying this in the browser